# How to join Spring JMS transactions from two different connection factories?

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-integration, spring-transactions, spring-jms

I am using different connection factories for sending and receiving messages, having trouble with partial commit issues incase of delivey failures. `jms:message-driven-channel-adapter` uses the `receiveConnectionFactory` ro receive the messages from the queue. `jms:outbound-channel-adapter` uses the `deliverConnectionFactory` to send the messages multiple to downstream queues. We have only one `JmsTransactionManager` which uses the `receiveConnectionFactory` and the `jms:outbound-channel-adapter` configured with `session-transacted="true"`.

```
<beans>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="receiveConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="receiveConnectionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
            <bean class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
                <property name="hostName" value="${mq.host}" />
                <property name="channel" value="${mq.channel}" />
                <property name="port" value="${mq.port}" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="${receive.factory.cachesize}" />
        <property name="cacheProducers" value="${receive.cache.producers.enabled}" />
        <property name="cacheConsumers" value="${receive.cache.consumers.enabled}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="deliverConnectionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
            <bean class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
                <property name="hostName" value="${mq.host}" />
                <property name="channel" value="${mq.channel}" />
                <property name="port" value="${mq.port}" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="${send.factory.cachesize}" />
        <property name="cacheProducers" value="${send.cache.producers.enabled}" />
        <property name="cacheConsumers" value="${send.cache.consumers.enabled}" />
    </bean>

    <tx:advice id="txAdviceNew" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="send" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdviceNew" pointcut="bean(inputChannel)" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdviceNew" pointcut="bean(errorChannel)" />
    </aop:config>

    <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
        id="mdchanneladapter" channel="inputChannel" task-executor="myTaskExecutor"
        connection-factory="receiveConnectionFactory" destination="inputQueue"
        error-channel="errorChannel" concurrent-consumers="${num.consumers}"
        max-concurrent-consumers="${max.num.consumers}" max-messages-per-task="${max.messagesPerTask}"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <jms:outbound-channel-adapter
        connection-factory="deliverConnectionFactory" session-transacted="true"
        destination-expression="headers.get('Deliver')" explicit-qos-enabled="true" />
</beans>
```

When there is MQ exception on any one destination, the partial commit occurs and then the failure queue commit happens. I am looking to see if I am missing some configuration to join the transactions so that the partial commit never happens.

I tried with only one connection factory for both send and receive (`receiveConnectionFactory`) and the parital commit is not happening, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried with only one connection factory for both send and receive (`receiveConnectionFactory`) and the parital commit is not happening, everything works as expected.

That's the right way to go in your case.

I see that your two `ConnectionFactories` are only different by their objects. Everything rest looks like the same target MQ server.

If you definitely can't live with only one `ConnectionFactory`, you should consider to use `JtaTransactionManager` or configure `org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager` for two `JmsTransactionManagers` - one per connection factory.

See Dave Syer's article on the matter: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html

Comment: Thanks @Artem for the quick reply. Yes, right now we are connected to same QManager for receive and send. We are preparing for future implementation of different QManager for send and receive. I will try implementing the JtaTransactionManager or ChainedTransactionManager and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Update - I added two JmsTransactionManagers - one per connection factory and the ChainedTransactionManager to join the transactions. Everything works as expected, no partial commits. Thanks @artem for posting the solution.